# Are these theorems equivalent (notation variation)?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Are these theorems equivalent (possible notation variation)?

> Let $A$ be an $m\times n$. Exactly one of the following system has a solution:
>
> 1)$Ax>0$
>
> 2)$A^ty=0,y\ge 0,y\neq 0$

And

> Exactly one of the following system has a solution:
>
> 1) $y^TA>0,$ for some $y\in\mathbb R^n$
>
> 2)$Ax=0,x\ge 0$ for some non-zero $x\in\mathbb R^m$

??

Comment: $(Ax)^T=x^TA^T$.  The second theorem is about the transpose of the matrix that appears in the first theorem.

Comment: @vadim123 I don't understand you. How the matrix in the 2nd theorem is the transpose of the matrix in the 1st theorem? They differ in the term $x^T$ and $y^T$